# ELASTICSEARCH - List the fields and unique values ​of a jsonlist the fields and unique values ​of a json

Tags: elasticsearch

I am searching the way to get uniques values of a field. in this case I don't want it to return a unique value from an aggregation counter, but the unique fields and values.

i.e
JSON:

```
     "name" : james,
      "city" : "chicago"
    },
    {
      "name" : james,
      "city" : "san francisco"
    },
    {
      "name" : james,
      "city" : "chicago"
    },
     {
      "name" : Mike,
      "city" : "chicago"
    },
     {
      "name" : Mike,
      "city" : "texas"
    },
     {
      "name" : Mike,
      "city" : "texas"
    },
     {
      "name" : Peter,
      "city" : "chicago"
    },
```

OUTPUT:

```
 "name" : james,
  "city" : "chicago"
},
{
  "name" : james,
  "city" : "san francisco"
},
 {
  "name" : Mike,
  "city" : "chicago"
},
 {
  "name" : Mike,
  "city" : "texas"
},
 {
  "name" : Peter,
  "city" : "chicago"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script) to that end. For instance, the following query would return you exactly all the unique combinations:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "[doc.name.value ?: 'no_name', doc.city.value ?: 'no_city'].join('-')"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that if it's just a one-off query to get some insights, that's ok, but if not, then it would be better to have another field that contains both values and that you can run a normal `terms` aggregation on.